# getting Error Element type is invalid in react

Tags: reactjs

App.js

```
    import './App.css';
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-dom";
    import SignInForm from "./components/SignInForm";
    import Login from "./login.svg";   
    function App() {
      return (
       <Router>
         <div className="App">

          <div className="App__Aside"></div>

          <div className="App__Form">

            <div className="PageSwitcher">

              <a href="#" className="PageSwitcher__Item">Sing In</a>
              <a href="#" className="PageSwitcher__Item PageSwitcher__Item--Active">Sign Up</a>

           </div>

           <div className="Form__Logo">
             <img src={Login}/>
           </div>

           <Route exact path="/" component={SignInForm}>
           </Route>

         </div>

        </div>
    </Router>
    );
  }

  export default App;
```

SignInForm.js

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    class SingInForm extends Component {
         render() {
              return (
                  <div className="FormCenter">
                  <form className="FormFields">
                     <div className="FormField">
                        <label className="FormField__Label" htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" className="FormField__Input" placeholder="Enter username" name="username"/>
                     </div>
                  </form>
                  </div>
            );
         }
     }
    export default SingInForm;
```

> expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BrowserRouter`, `Route` `Navlink` etc are exported from `react-router-dom`.

In your code base, change the following import statement -

`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-dom";`

to -

`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";`

Answer (score 0):

*App.js*

`import SignInForm from "./components/SignInForm";`

to

`import SignInForm from "./components/SigninForm";`

The wrong file imported *SigninForm.js* in your file.